# Fuse vs Switchyard

Tags: fuseesb, jboss-esb

I need to know what is the difference between Jboss Fuse and Switchyard. Switchyard website says it will be replacing Jboss ESB. This brings the question what is the difference between FUSE and Switchyard where both will work as ESB

Comment: There is a little bit of information about the difference, at this page: http://www.jboss.org/products/fsw.html

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Switchyard is actually at the top of  "JBoss Fuse Service Works" (which is the new "JBoss SOA Plattform") as a framework for service-oriented applications.

Fuse provides Camel as the framework for integration that use the enterprise integration patterns (EIP),  but doesn't offers the features like a SOA Plattform (like service registry or UDDI ...).

They are both ESBs but for different use case; one is for SOA and the other is for integration, and they're also based on different containers; Fuse Service Works has the JBoss EAP as container, an J2EE spec, and FUse is based on Karaf container, an OSGi 'spec'.

I hope i've helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Jboss released a new version of Fuse by integrating with Switchyard and several other Apache related framework, refer them in this [link](http://developers.redhat.com/products/fuse/overview/). Switchyard is a Composite framework, Where in you can do lot many integrations such as file poller, http,soap, webservice, BPEL ,BPM and Java Beans etc.

Jboss says you can work with EAP 6.4 server in order to work on Jboss Fuse(Switchyard)  related things,but vanilla installation of EAP 6.4 server wont detect Switchyard applications through JBDS. You want to install JBoss Fuse over your EAP server. Refer [link](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse/6.2.1/html/Installation_on_JBoss_EAP/Installing_Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse_on_EAP.html) here to know more details regards to that.